# Can't disable background blur with NSPopover

Tags: cocoa, osx-yosemite, nspopover

I'm having no luck trying to get NSPopover back to its 10.9 appearance when running in 10.10. I have a popover which is attached to an NSView that the user drags around. The popover **must** be transparent so the user can still see the position of the other UI elements underneath.

All works fine under 10.9 but now under 10.10 with Apple's new gimmicky blurs, I can't seem to get back to the same appearance on 10.10 (unless like me, the user has enabled "Reduce Transparency" in System Preferences > Accessibility. A preference change I can't enforce on end users!).

Have tried:

```
self.draggingPopover.appearance = NSPopoverAppearanceHUD;
self.popoverView.superview.appearance = [NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameAqua];
self.popoverView.appearance = [NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameAqua];
```

None of which make any difference to the popover's appearance on screen.

drawRect in my view subclass fills the background with my chosen color but ignores the alpha value and the popover is opaque.

Similarly I can use `self.popoverView.layer.backgroundColor = ...` but the alpha value is ignored there too!

Comment: Seems that since 10.10 the popover content view's superview (NSPopoverFrame) draws with full opacity, so no matter what you do in the content view, transparency isn't supported.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
[popover setAppearance:(NSPopoverAppearance)[NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameAqua]];
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same result as setting appearance on the view. The blur is disabled but I can't draw any transparency into the background of the view. I've even tried setting layer.backgroundColor on the content view's superview (NSPopoverFrame) but again it ignores any transparency.

Answer (score 0):

If a requirement is that the popover is transparent (regardless of any future design changes to popover), could you just set the popover window's (i.e. the popoverView's `-window`) alphaValue to some other value < 1.0?

Comment: No because the content will be transparent too. I need only the background to be 50% opacity but the text on top to be 100% opacity.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Aqua` appearance in the storyboard as well. Select the `NSPopover`'s content view and use this setting:

[image]