# Bleed through from NSButton checkbox on non-transparent NSPopover

Tags: swift, user-interface, cocoa

I'm using a NSPopover for my menubar application and it seems that its default aqua theme (and also light and dark) paints it with a semi-transparent background.

I want an opaque background.

So I searched SO and found I can set a background color for the contentViewController like so:

```
    if let popoverView = popover.contentViewController?.view.superview {
        popoverView.wantsLayer = true
        popoverView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.controlBackgroundColor.withAlphaComponent(1.0).cgColor
    }
```

That works, but any UI controls within that view controller draw their backgrounds as transparent, as seen like so:

[image]

I've tried embedding the UI controls within a NSBox but I get the same transparent background paint.

What's the solution?

Here's a [sample project](https://github.com/dboydor/popover-problem) that demonstrates what I'm seeing:

EDIT: There is similar SO ticket but the poster wanted a transparent background instead of opaque. In any case, none of the solutions solved my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't disable background blur with NSPopover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876645/cant-disable-background-blur-with-nspopover)

Comment: Yes, a duplicate but the poster wanted a transparent background instead of opaque.  In any case, none of the solutions solved my problem.

Comment: `popover.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .aqua)` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` works for me.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  It does fix it.  I had that in my code in my main project and had tried that but it wasn't working there.  Fixes everything in my test project though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, thanks to Willeke, is to add this within AppDelegate.applicationDidFinishLaunching()

```
    popover.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .aqua)
```