# NSSegmentedControl - Odd appearance when placed in blur view

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsview, nspopover, nssegmentedcontrol

I have a macOS app with a simple popover view and a `NSSegmentedControl` placed within it. Everything works fine, apart from the odd appearance of the segmented control. It has this weird square background when placed in the pop over view.

[image]

Is there any way to get rid of this?

Comment: Similar questions: [Can't disable background blur with NSPopover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876645/cant-disable-background-blur-with-nspopover/41476844#41476844) and [Bleed through from NSButton checkbox on non-transparent NSPopover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895870/bleed-through-from-nsbutton-checkbox-on-non-transparent-nspopover).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, labels inside `NSSegmentedControl` ignore vibrancy effect.

To fix it, put `NSSegmentedControl` inside `NSVisualEffectView` with `material` set to `popover`.

Comment: Thank you so much, perfect solution!